# Why does (int 10) produce a Long instance?

Tags: clojure, type-coercion, clojure-java-interop

Why does `(int 10)` not produce an instance of type `java.lang.Integer`?

```
; why Long here?
=> (type (int 10))
; java.lang.Long

; this one is also Long, why not java.lang.Number?
=> (type (num 10))
; java.lang.Long

=> (type (double 10))
; java.lang.Double
=> (type (long 10))
; java.lang.Long
=> (type (float 10))
; java.lang.Float
=> (type (short 10))
; java.lang.Short
=> (type (bigint 10))
; clojure.lang.BigInt
=> (type (bigdec 10))
; java.math.BigDecimal
=> (type (boolean 10))
; java.lang.Boolean
=> (type (char 10))
; java.lang.Character
=> (type (byte 10))
; java.lang.Byte
```

Comment: It was fixed in Clojure 1.5: http://dev.clojure.org/jira/browse/CLJ-820    I tested it in Clojure 1.6 and (type (int 10)) gives java.lang.Integer.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Clojure deals only with `long` integers internally. `(int)` is used to cast a `long` to an `int` for calling Java methods that expect an `int` argument.

In this case `(int 10)` does indeed return a Java `int`, but Clojure then promotes the `int` back to a `long`. `(type)` uses `(class)` to find out the type of its argument (in this case), and therefore the `long` gets boxed into a `java.lang.Long`.

You can produce `java.lang.Integer` by using one of the `java.lang.Integer` constructors or factory methods:

```
user> (type (Integer. 10))
java.lang.Integer

user> (type (Integer/valueOf 10))
java.lang.Integer

user> (type (Integer/decode "10"))
java.lang.Integer

...
```

`(num)` will upcast its argument to the abstract class `java.lang.Number`, but `(type)` will return the actual type of its argument, i.e. `java.lang.Long` again.

Answer (score 7):

`int` is a cast to primitive integer for interop calls. Since each of type calls takes an `Object` things get boxed again and Clojure (>= 1.3) boxes to `Long` and `Double`. If you need an `Integer` you have to create one.

```
user=> (type (Integer/valueOf 10))
java.lang.Integer
```

Comment: So why does `(.compareTo (Integer. 10) (int 10))` result in `ClassCastException java.lang.Long cannot be cast to java.lang.Integer`?  Is this not an example of Java interop?

Comment: `.compareTo` takes `Object`, so the result of `(int 10)` is immediately boxed back to a `Long` resulting in the exception inside `compareTo` when it tries to cast to `Integer`. It's a nice interaction between Clojure's boxing and the fact that generics like `java.lang.Comparable` in Java aren't reified.

Comment: @DaveRay According to http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html `compareTo` takes an `Integer`, which does derive from `Object`.  Is it correct to say that `(int)` should only be used when an `int` instance is required, it does not work for when an `Integer` instance is needed.

Comment: @spoon16 As I said: "primitive integer".

Comment: >= 1.3 is incorrect: this confusing behavior is reverted in 1.4

Comment: @amalloy, What is the behavior in 1.4? does (int) produce an Integer?

Comment: @spoon16 Yes, it does. But don't take my word for it: try it out!